# Does haskell have a conditional operator such as "x == y ? a : b" in C++ or ifelse(x==y, a, b) in R?

Tags: haskell, conditional-operator

Does haskell have a conditional operator that performs as

```
x == y ? a : b
```

in C++ or

```
ifelse(x==y, a, b)
```

in R ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Haskell's `if` performs exactly as you want.

```
if x == y then a else b
```

---

As Lee mentioned, there is a `bool` function in `Data.Bool` that does the same thing. Also, thanks to Haskell's lazyness, `bool someLongComputation something True` does not run the long computation..

Comment: Sure, but note that `if`-`then`-`else` is a built-in construct of the language, not an operator. For instance, it doesn't make sense to ask for the type of `if`.

Comment: Yes, but... user defined functions... `ifelse p a b = if p then a else b`.  Or tupling as in R `ifelse (p,a,b) = if p then a else b`.

Comment: @Jubobs `?:` in C++ is a built-in construct of the language, too.

Comment: The fact that `if` is lazy in Haskell is not peculiar at all: `if` is lazy in virtually any language. That is, there is practically no language where `if True then something else someLongComputation` causes the long computation to be evaluated.

Comment: @chi Oops, I meant to talk about ``bool``. Thanks for pointing this.

Answer (score 19):

Apart from `if` or `Data.Bool.bool`, which do indeed just what you want, you can also define such an operator yourself in Haskell!

```
infixr 1 ?
(?) :: Bool -> a -> a -> a
(True ? a) _ = a
(False ? _) b = b
```

> GHCi> 3==2 ? "equal" $ "nonequal"
>              "nonequal"
> GHCi> 3==3 ? "equal" $ "nonequal"
> "equal"

Comment: I like this definition of `?`, `c ? (t,e) = if c then t else e`.

Comment: Nice abuse of `$` and precedence.

Answer (score 14):

There is the `bool` function in `Data.Bool`:

```
import Data.Bool
bool b a (x == y)
```

Comment: is there a reason to use this vs "if then else" besides terseness? is there any performance difference or difference in corner cases?

Comment: @daj Based on [its definition](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/src/Data-Bool.html#bool), `bool` shouldn't be associated with any prohibitive overhead.

Comment: @daj: The only reason to use `bool` would be to pass an under-applied form to a higher-order function, like `map (bool b a) xs`.